# Plotting confidence intervals-lines in one graph with means inside

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, mean, confidence-interval

I need to plot 12 confidence intervals in one graph using MATLAB and each with mean marked inside. Any ideas how I can do it? You can find an example in the following picture:
[image: example plot]

I am using a code below for computing confidence intervals:

```
S=10; E=9; sigma=0.1; r=0.06; T=1;
Dt=1e-3; N=T/Dt; M=2^17;

V = zeros(M,1);
for i=1:M
    Sfinal = S*exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*T+sigma*sqrt(T)*randn);
    V(i)=exp(-r*T)*max(Sfinal-E,0);
end
aM=mean(V); bM=std(V);
conf=[aM-1.96*bM/sqrt(M),aM+1.96*bM/sqrt(M)]
```

Comment: Have you looked into the [`errorbar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html) function?

Comment: not yet, but will have a look! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instead of your loop, you can just write:

```
V = exp(-r*T)*max(S*exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*T+sigma*sqrt(T)*randn(M,1))-E,0);
```

`randn(M,1)` create all `M` random values at once, and because all other values are scalars, you can vectorize your calculation by simply put it in the formula for `V` (this way, there also no need in initializing `V` with zeros).

And for plotting the error bar use [`errorbar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html):

```
errorbar(aM,conf(1),conf(2))
```